# Computer Stuck on Loading screen

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, computer-building

I  was watching a movie on my PC (motherboard ASRock conroe945PL-Glan).

The movie froze and the colors changed.

I tried to restart the PC and now it is stuck on windows loading logo, and then restarting again.

I tried my old HDD which was already installed on the motherboard and it worked fine.

Please help me out, I won't to lose the files on the other HDD.

Comment: I suggest you rewrite your question as it is very difficult to understand the question.

Comment: Colors got changed? Was it a blue screen? Blue screen of death as its called (BSOD)

Comment: When you boot from the second HDD, can you access the files on the first one (e.g., access it as `D:` or `H:` or something)?  How about if you boot from a live CD?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to run a live OS distribution on it to check if the problem is caused by software or hardware. If it runs okay, the problem is probably caused by software or the HDD itself. If it was a software problem, reinstalling Windows should help. When you choose Upgrade as the installation method, you should lose no user data on HDD.

Answer (score 0):

This happens often when some hardware item is gone bad. 
The file system gets corrupt and windows won't boot. Don't worry.

Most likely your RAM, VGA or the HDD itself. You can try pressing F9 right after your boot screen to boot into safe mode.

Once there, try running a scan disk on your root drive.

```
Right click your drive under my computer & select properties then tools then check now.
```

Leave the defaults and restart your computer.

Let the scan run and repair any errors. Hopefully your problem will be resolved.

If not, you can put the Windows CD in your CD drive, boot from it and select repair windows.

[How to repair a corrupt windows installation](http://www.maximumpc.com/how-to-repair-a-faulty-windows-installation-without-reformatting/)